# How to change status of online user to offline user in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am making a program using firebase database. A lot of users are connected using android phones to database and answer some questions. If user answers incorrectly then I want to break the connection of that user to firebase database. To be more precise, 10 users are connected to firebase and take question from table all of then answer to a question and 4 of them answered incorrectly. I wanna kick those 4 users from game. Is it possible in firebase? I saw onDisconnect() function but I don`t know whether it works or not. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the users that answer wrong not to be able to add more data.
Disconnecting the user to the RTD seems like a way to do it, but it seems too much of a problem considering is not safe.

What I recommend is to:

1. Create a set of rules that prevent malicious clients to keep
   adding data after a wrong answer
2. Have an RTD structure that suits
   your purpose
3. Use Functions to control the business logic safely
4. Make the clients reflect on the UI what is happening

The rules should be something like: if the user has true on a validation node with the same id as the current game, then the user can write answers if the validation node is false then the user wrongfully answered a previous question and therefore can't write more answers. We will get back at this.

Your database structure should be something like this:

```
{
  "questionnaires": {
    "questionnaire_id_1": {
      "question_1": {
        "question": "How much is 2 + 2",
        "alternatives": {
          "a": 4,
          "b": 3,
          "c": 2
        }
      },
      "question_2": {
        "question": "How much is 0 + 2",
        "alternatives": {
          "a": 4,
          "b": 3,
          "c": 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "answers": {
    "questionnaire_id_1": {
      "question_1": "a",
      "question_2": "c"
    }
  },
  "user_answers": {
    "questionnaire_id_1": {
      "uid_1": {
        "question_1": "a",
        "question_2": "c"
      },
      "uid_2": {
        "question_1": "a",
        "question_2": "c"
      },
      "uid_3": {
        "question_1": "a"
      }
    }
  },
  "questionnaires_permissions": {
    "questionnaire_id_1": {
      "uid_1": true,
      "uid_2": true,
      "uid_3": false
    },
    "questionnaire_id_2": {
      "uid_1": true,
      "uid_2": true,
      "uid_3": true
    }
  }
}
```

There are `questionnaires` for the user to choose. When the user chooses a questionnaire it will trigger an [onCall Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that will validate if the user has previously selected the questionnaire. The onCall Function will check if the `questionnaires_permissions/{user_uid}` exists. If it doesn't exist it will reply `ok move forward` and will create it, if it does exist and is true then it will respond and `ok move forward` as well, but if it is false it means the user previously made a mistake, then it will response `user failed the test`. This way the UI can reflect what at the first time selecting a questionnaire or by re-entering one.

The `questionnaires` nodes allow the user to read all the questions, the `answers` node has the correct answers to be read-only by Functions, and the `user_answers` node has the user actual answers (written by the user).

You need to have an [RTD Functions listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) for the `users_answers/{questionnaire_id}/{uid}/{question}` creation. When an answer is created by the user the Functions will be triggered and will check if it is a correct answer. If it is incorrect, then it will be marked as `false` on the `questionnaires_permissions/{questionnaire_id}/{uid}` node.

The client has to have a real-time listener for the `questionnaires_permissions/{questionnaire_id}/{uid}` if it changes to false, then the UI has to display a warning telling the user the last question was wrong.

The last 2 steps could also be a single operation using an `onCall`.

Now we have to look at the database rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "questionnaires": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": false
    },
    "answers": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    },
    "user_answers": {
      "$questionnaire_id": {
        "$uid": {
          "$question_id": {
            ".read": false,
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && root.child('questionnaires_permissions').child($questionnaire_id).val() == true"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "questionnaires_permissions": {
      "$questionnaire_id": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So if by any reason a malicios client try to write after a wrong answer, it won't be possible because the database rules won't allow it

Comment: Great answer cutiko!